# /usr/include Directory on WSL

Tags: python, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pybind11

I am using WSL on Windows and in the directory `/usr/include` I have a subdirectory called `python3.8`. As I understood the `/usr/include` includes the header files for C compilers.

I have installed `python3.10` but it seems that `python3.8` exists by default in WSL. Hence, I am having some conflicts with the directory `python3.8` in `/usr/include` when I am trying to do python bindings with C++ using `pybind11`.

From the resulting error that I get when trying to import pybind11 header in C++ it is obvious that the program is looking for `/usr/include/python3.10` (which does not exist) instead of `/usr/include/python3.8`.

As a solution I created a new directory called `python3.10` in `/usr/include` and copied all the content inside `/usr/include/python3.8`. Thus, the problem disappeared and the program ran correctly but I am not quite sure that this is the best approach.

EDIT:

CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(pybindproject)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(module_name main.cpp)
```

I have got pybind11 using: `git clone https://github.com/pybind/pybind11.git`

Comment: Please include your `setup.py` and/or your `CMakeLists.txt` so we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find where the python 3.10 was installed and find the include directory in the python 3.10 folder.

On WSL, just look at where you installed python, probably in your home directory if you installed from the tarball, then add to your environment C include path:

```bash
export CPATH='/home/../Python-3.10.6/Include':$CPATH
```

If you're compiling with GCC from the command line, you can also manually specify an include path with the -I flag, like so:

```
g++ -I/whatever/path/to/python/include/dir foo.cpp
```

Comment: I have searched for the python3.10 folder and there is no associated `include` directory.

Comment: the include folder is distributed with any download of Python from Python.org. If worst comes to worst, I would just redownload the compressed distributable if you haven't already done so. There's no harm in doing a cp "$HOME/python3.10/include" -t "/usr/include/python3.10" after changing your other python3.10 back to python3.8. You'll also have to rename the copied include directory to python3.10 after the cp invocation, but as long at the headers match the version of the interpreter that you're using you should be fine. I would recommend isolating the python executable from your path, too

Comment: Yes, it did help. I also had some installation issues with pybind11 that I managed to solve, so everything works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo apt-get install python3.10-dev`

I know this has already been answered. However I had to take a slightly different approach because I installed `python3.10` using deadsnakes on ubuntu with the command `sudo apt-get install python3.10`. I tried the accepted answer, but only to find that I ran into the error: `fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory`. This error was easily googled which redirected me to this resolved [github issue](https://github.com/okfn/piati/issues/65)